# Sharepoint audit logs using javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help me to get recently visited document using audit logs in sharepoint  using javascript object model

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, The `SPAudit API` is not available via the Client Object Model.

You can use Server-side object model as mention at [Auditing - A Built-in Feature of SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431342/Auditing-A-Built-in-Feature-of-SharePoint)