# Collect the latest Modified and Modified By info for each user that has contributed to a list. Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, workflow, custom, custom-javascript

A customer has asked me to display a table that shows everyone who has modified a list and **the most recent modification** they each made.

It would look like:
Sally Modified 3 hours ago

Jack Modified 4 days ago

Amy Modified 12 days ago

I don't know how to pull only the latest modified item out of a list using JS. Can anyone help?? If there's some way to do this OOTB or with a workflow, I'll take that too. I haven't been able to find anything online so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no REST API that you could use from JS to show audit data on a SharePoint page.

Read more on this [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190555/sharepoint-audit-logs-using-javascript)

However, you could create your own Web API using **Server Side Model** and then call it from JS to retrieve Audit Data from SharePoint.

For more information visit [this post](https://www.spjeff.com/2017/02/12/spauditapi-read-sharepoint-audit-logs-from-javascript-over-rest/)

Comment: thanks so much Matiur

Comment: You could mark the question as answered if it satisfies your query